# sql developer version 20.4 ssh ui no field

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, apple-m1, oracle18c

i am using `sqldeveloper-20.4.1.407.0006-macosx.app`
when i switch my connection type to ssh
there is no field for hostname and other field
when i click test or connect the error `Status : Failure -Test failed: Required property 'hostname' cannot be null or empty`

my device is mbp m1

[screenshot sqldeveloper no field for ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rMCC.png)

```
About
-----

Oracle SQL Developer 20.4.1.407
 Version 20.4.1.407
Build 407.0006

IDE Version: 12.2.1.5.42.201006.2103
Product ID: oracle.sqldeveloper
Product Version: 20.4.1.407.0006

Version
-------

Component   Version
=========   =======
Oracle IDE  20.4.1.407.0006
Java(TM) Platform   1.8.0_292
Versioning Support  20.4.1.407.0006

Properties
----------

Name    Value
====    =====

Extensions
----------

Name    Identifier  Version Status  Registration Time   Initialization Time Total Time
====    ==========  ======= ======  =================   =================== ==========
```

Comment: First you need to create SSH connection from menu `view-->SSH` then you can access created SSH in new connection

Comment: Refer this [link](https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/sql-developer-ssh-connection/)